# How to change the color of clustered pins in BingMaps?

Tags: javascript, svg, bing-maps

I am trying to change the color of the clustered pushpins from the default purple to something else.  I don't see anything obvious in the documentation.  I tried the following:

```
var layer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(clusterPins, {
    color: 'yellow'
});
```

but it has no effect. Oddly enough, the individual pins themselves (when they are not clustered) can be colored:

```
var clusterPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(location, {
    color: 'yellow'
});
```

Do I really have to go the route of creating an SVG just to change the color of the clustered pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the clusteredPinCallback option to set the style of clustered pushpins. For example:

```
var clusterLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.ClusterLayer(pins, {
    clusteredPinCallback: function(clusterPin){
        clusterPin.setOptions({ color: 'yellow' });
    }
});
```

This is done as most devs want to customize the cluster based on the cluster size or content inside the cluster. Here is a more in-depth code sample: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Clustering_Customization